# Xcode 8.0 beta 6, Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'NSInteger' (aka 'long') to 'CGSWindow' (aka 'int')

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

Seems I’m having some growing pains associated with the Xcode 8 beta and 64bit migration. In searching I’ve found a few related questions but not one specifically related to solving an ‘NSInteger' (aka 'long') to 'CGSWindow' (aka 'int') error.

Anyone here know how to get it going the right way round?

here's an example:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface CustomWindow : NSWindow {
    // this point is used in dragging to mark the initial click location
    NSPoint initialLocation;
}

@property (assign) NSPoint initialLocation;

@end


#import "CustomWindow.h"

#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>

@implementation CustomWindow

@synthesize initialLocation;

/*
 In Interface Builder, the class for the window is set to this subclass. Overriding the initializer
 provides a mechanism for controlling how objects of this class are created.
 */
- (id)initWithContentRect:(NSRect)contentRect
                styleMask:(NSUInteger)aStyle
                  backing:(NSBackingStoreType)bufferingType
                    defer:(BOOL)flag {

    // Using NSBorderlessWindowMask results in a window without a title bar.
    self = [super initWithContentRect:contentRect styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO];
    if (self != nil) {
        // Start with no transparency for all drawing into the window
        [self setAlphaValue:1.0];
        // Turn off opacity so that the parts of the window that are not drawn into are transparent.
        [self setOpaque:NO];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Which line is causing the error?

Comment: oh, sorry. it's the 'styleMask line' in 'initWithContentRect', and this is an apple example:   https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/samplecode/RoundTransparentWindow/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the documentation for `NSWindow initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:`. What is the type for the `styleMask` parameter?

```
- (instancetype)initWithContentRect:(NSRect)contentRect
                          styleMask:(NSWindowStyleMask)style
                            backing:(NSBackingStoreType)bufferingType
                              defer:(BOOL)flag;
```

So you need to change `NSInteger` to `NSWindowStyleMask`.

Now look at the documentation for `NSWindowStyleMask`. `NSBorderlessWindowMask` is not one of the listed values (it's an old, deprecated value). Use `NSWindowStyleMaskBorderless`.

So your code should be:

```
- (id)initWithContentRect:(NSRect)contentRect
                styleMask:(NSWindowStyleMask)aStyle
                  backing:(NSBackingStoreType)bufferingType
                    defer:(BOOL)flag {

    // Using NSBorderlessWindowMask results in a window without a title bar.
    self = [super initWithContentRect:contentRect styleMask: NSWindowStyleMaskBorderless backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO];
    if (self != nil) {
        // Start with no transparency for all drawing into the window
        [self setAlphaValue:1.0];
        // Turn off opacity so that the parts of the window that are not drawn into are transparent.
        [self setOpaque:NO];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Ah yes!! Seems so obvious now.  :)   thank you rmaddy!